# How to program GNSS with SIMCOM A7670 and Arduino

Tags: arduino, gps

I bought a [SIMCOM A7670SA with LTEGNSS antenna](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004176703311.html), and although I am able to use LTE to send a message to my phone using an Arduino, I cannot find a way to use the GNSS feature. I found this [website with datasheets](https://www.simcom.com/product/A7670X.html), but I cannot understand how to program it. Does anyone know how I could figure it out?

I tried searching it up online, reading the datasheet, looking at the files on the company's [website](https://www.simcom.com/product/A7670X.html), but I can't figure out how to program it.

Thanks